# Angular Dynamic form formcontrol name gets cleared

Tags: angular, dynamicform

I am iterating the input field  in ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let x of y; let z = index" >
   <input type="text" formControlName="{{x.key}}" matInput>
</div>
```

the values from db are getting populated while editing, If i make changes to the input field and call api for insert the records are getting added to db.
But after api call the formControlName in not getting set but i can see the empty input field only, as formControl name is not there the values are missing.

Is this due to the field not getting re initialized?
How can this issue be fixed?

Comment: can you share code?. what you have done till now.

Comment: Do you mean angular dynamic form?

Comment: did you try resting form by yourFormName.reset();

Comment: I think it is same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944605/dynamic-form-with-formcontrolname asked by OP again..

Comment: I think what you're looking for here is `FormArray` and `patchValue`